# Difference stringstream and ostringstream

Tags: c++

I was trying out the below snippet but it is not giving the desired output:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
void MyPrint(ostream& stream)
{
    cout<<stream.rdbuf()<< endl;
}
int main()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<"hello there";
    MyPrint(ss);                //Prints fine

    ostringstream oss;
    oss<<"hello there";
    MyPrint(oss);               //Does not print anything
    getchar();
}
```

I am aware that the only possible differences between `stringstream` and `ostringstream` is that the later forces the direction and is a bit faster than `stringstream`.

Am I missing out on anything?

PS: A similar question was posted earlier but didn't get any answers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`std::stringstream` and `std::ostringstream` pass different
flags to the `std::stringbuf`.  In particular, the
`std::stringbuf` of an `std::ostringstream` does not support
reading.  And `std::cout << stream.rdbuf()` is a read operation
on the streambuf.

The way to extract characters from an `std::ostringstream` is by
using the `std::ostringstream::str()` function.

Answer (score 1):

stringstream shouldn't be thought of as a bidirectional implementation of ostringstream and istringstream.  It is implemented as a derrived class of both ostringstream and istringstream, which is why it implements both input and output capabilities.

Choosing which one to use depends on what it is used for.  If you only need to write data to it on a stream without being able to access the data via a stream, then an ostringstream is all you would need.  However, if you want to implement bidirectional on something you provide to an API but restrict it, you can cast it:

```
stringstream ss;  // My bidirectional stream

ostringstream *p_os = &ss;  // Now an output stream to be passed to something only allowed to write to it.

int bytes = collectSomeData(p_oss);
```